# C# form Cut control and paste in panel,control code not work

Tags: c#, winforms

Step 1: create a C# Windows Forms app project

Step 2: add a button, label control and one panel to the form, button and label outside the panel:

[image: Add Controls]

Step 3: double-click Button control and add this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label1.Visible == true)
    { 
        label1.Visible = false;  
    }
    else
    { 
        label1.Visible = true;   
    }
}
```

Step 4: run the app, click button1 -> label1 disappears.

Step 5: stop app, back to form design. Cut button control and paste in panel (Not draw drop):

[image]

Step 6: run app again, click button, code does not work.

Why does the button control code not work? How to fix it without coding again?

Comment: Have you looked at the events view of the button's properties (or at the designer generated code for the button in the `.designer.cs` file. My guess is that the button's event doesn't survive the cut/paste cycle. Have you tried copy/paste + delete? If want you want to do doesn't work, it's either by design or it will never get _fixed_ (WinForms is 20 years old and hasn't seen much maintenance in a decade)

Comment: OT: there's no need for that `if/else` in that event handler. All you're doing is toggling a `bool`, so just do that: `label1.Visible = !label1.Visible;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a link created between the control and the event handler method. When you cut the control, you effectively delete it, so that link is removed. When you paste the control, the link is not recreated automatically because there's no reason to. If you want the link restored, you need to recreate it yourself. To do that, select the control, open the *Properties* window, click the *Events* button and then select the existing method from the drop-down list for the appropriate event.

A better solution is to not cut and paste in the first place. Instead, drag and drop. When you do that, the control is never deleted so the event handler registration is never deleted either. Note that you can also use the *Document Outline* window to move child controls into and out of containers. You may still have to adjust their position though, either by drag and drop or in the *Properties* window.

BTW, if you want to see the difference before and after a cut and paste operation, just open the designer code file for your form. As a test, add two `Button` controls to your form and double-click each to create `Click` event handlers. Cut one of the controls and then paste it again, then look at the designer code for each. You'll be able to see the event handler registration for one that is missing for the other.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have one more button so that you function doesn't work please share code

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and should have been posted as a comment. If you can't post comments because you don't have enough reputation, perform some actions to increase your reputation. Posting answers that aren't answers is not OK.

Comment: If you want to say something that is not an answer, please post a comment instead.